# Usage of k.clear_session() and tf.reset_default_graph() to clear graph between subsequent models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I can"t seem to clear the graph properly when loading multiple models subsequently.

```
k.clear_session()   
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

is just closing the program in Python after the first model is loaded.
If remove the above lines, I am able to load subsequent models, but then I run into the memory leak.

```
>>> import keras
Using TensorFlow backend.
>>> keras.__version__
'2.2.4'
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.__version__
'1.8.0'
>>> 





def evaluate_models(models_path_dir):
    models_paths = [os.path.join(models_path_dir, model) for model in os.listdir(models_path_dir) if model.endswith(".hdf5")]
    models_pairs = get_model_key(models_paths, global_model_keys)
    print(len(model_pairs)) #15
    for model_pair in models_pairs:
        model_path,model_key = model_pair
        img_height, img_width = 480, 480
        evaluate_validation_data(model_path, model_key)



def evaluate_validation_data(model_path,model_key):
    preprocess =  model_key
    valid_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function = preprocess)
    valid_generator = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size = (img_height, img_width),
    batch_size = 30, 
    class_mode = 'categorical',
    shuffle = False)

    model = load_model(model_path)
    print("model path",model_path)
    print("image size", (img_height, img_width))
    print( model.evaluate_generator(valid_generator))
    k.clear_session()
    tf.reset_default_graph()
```

Is my usage of k.clear_session() and tf.reset_default() incorrect?

Thank you.

UPDATE:

I tried changing my code as follows and I am still running into the same problem:

```
def evaluate_validation_data(model_path,model_key):
        preprocess =  model_key
        valid_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function = preprocess)
        valid_generator = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_data_dir,
        target_size = (img_height, img_width),
        batch_size = 10, 
        class_mode = 'categorical',
        shuffle = False)

        model = load_model(model_path)
        print("model path",model_path)
        print("image size", (img_height, img_width))
        print( model.evaluate_generator(valid_generator))
        k.clear_session()
        #tf.reset_default_graph()




>>> import keras
Using TensorFlow backend.
>>> keras.__version__
'2.2.4'
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.__version__
'1.8.0'
>>>
```

Here is the what happens when the program executes:

```
39
Found 374 images belonging to 5 classes.
loaded model
model path E:\USER\TEST\model.hdf5
image size (480, 480)
[0.5056040882665843, 0.8609625604700915]
Found 374 images belonging to 5 classes.
```

And then closes

Comment: I think you should use only `K.clear_session()`

Comment: @DanielMöller  I Just tried and the program automatically closes after first model evaulation (even with only `K.clear_session()`. If I get rid of the K.clear_session(), it will load many models sequentially and eventually crash due to OOM error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a bug with Keras above 2.2 and tf 1.8?

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10399

and I need to downgrade Keras to 2.1?

EDIT:

Just tested.
Downgrading it 2.1 take cares of the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Loose the `tf.reset_default_graph()` and you should be good.
As for the memory leaks, be sure you are running Keras 2.2.4 (and preferably tensorflow>=1.10 has better keras integration), I had a similar issue with Keras 2.2.2 crashing when loading multiple models in sequence and it disapeared after I updated to Keras 2.2.4.

Comment: I got rid of that line and I am still running into the problem when I use K.clear_session() only.
I am using Keras 2.2.4 and tensorflow 1.8.  Thank you for your reply.

Looking at the output (see updated OP), it seems to crash before loading the second model. It crashes after loading the generator.